# How to find venues for publishing short meta-analysis papers

Tags: publications, computer-science, research-topic

How to find venues for publishing short meta-analysis papers (e.g., keywords, co-authorship networks, etc.) in Human Computer Interaction?

Comment: HCI?  Hyperconverged infrastructure ... Human-computer Interaction ... Heme-controlled inhibitor ... Hale-colloidal iron ...   or perhaps HCl = hydrocloride, it is difficult to distinguish I from l with this font.

Comment: I take it you disagree so strongly with [your previous (now deleted) question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/202492/17254) being considered a shopping question that you felt it was somehow appropriate to just repost it without any edits to address those concerns?

Comment: @GEdgar It's Human Computer Interaction.

Comment: @Anyon, I did not disagree. I just wanted to post it as a clear question so that I can make the question clear for the people. I hope you understand.

Comment: Technically our shopping policy does not forbid "how can I find X" as long as it's not looking for a list of or particular "X". But, I don't really think this is the form of question we want, I'd expect a bit more explanation and identification of why this is a problem. Given the post history, it feels like you're just trying to sidestep the policy rather than formulate a useful question for others.

Comment: So, while I think this question should not be *closed* as shopping, I do think it's reasonable for people to choose to downvote if they feel it's lacking research effort (see the downvote tooltip).

Answer (score 1):

Look at where similar papers have been published. Google Scholar (or any aggregate search engine) is your friend here - search something like "meta-analysis [topic]".If you can't find *any* similar papers there may be other issues you need to address before you start working on something.